# Neo4j get all parents and grand parents

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an unknown-level tree hierarchy stored in the Neo4j graph database.
How can I retrieve all parents and grand parents for a given nodes.
So in the following example, node "a" has parent and grand parent "c", "e", and "b"

```
CREATE (a {id:1})
CREATE (b {id:2})
CREATE (c {id:3})
CREATE (d {id:4})
CREATE (e {id:5})

MATCH (a), (c) WHERE a.id = 1 AND c.id = 3 CREATE (a) -[r:PARENT]-> (c)
MATCH (c), (e) WHERE c.id = 3 AND e.id = 5 CREATE (c) -[r:PARENT]-> (e)
MATCH (a), (b) WHERE a.id = 1 AND b.id = 2 CREATE (a) -[r:PARENT]-> (b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need parents and grandparents in one list then you can use:

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a.id = 1  
WITH a 
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:PARENT*1..2]->(pg)  
RETURN a, collect(pg) as parents
```

In case you need parents in one and grandparents in another list:

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a.id = 1   
WITH a  
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:PARENT]->(p)   
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:PARENT]->(gp)   
RETURN a, collect(p) as parents, collect(gp) as grandparents
```

`WITH` is used to pass the matched node to the following sub-queries.

`OPTIONAL MATCH` is used so that the query returns results even if parents or grandparents nodes are not available for any node.

**Suggestion:**
consider using labels for nodes e.g. Person